# MVC3 referencing dlls installed in GAC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reference, web-config, assemblies, gac

I have some legacy dlls installed as part of a asp.net MSI setup package. All dlls are installed into the GAC. On asp.net I was able to reference dlls in GAC by placing such entries into the web.config file

```
<add assembly="MY.DEPENDENCY.MODULE, Version=1.2.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=qwertyuiop"/>
```

I did the same thing as above in MVC3 but my source complains it can't find the expected references. have anyone else know or done this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding a reference from inside VS? Right click on References>Add Reference

Comment: its not like its in a custom folder on some server, it is in the GAC!

Comment: @user742276 You are incorrect. Assemblies in the GAC are never referenced by folder location. That would spoil the whole point of the GAC!

Answer (score 0):

When you reference a dll via the Add Reference,  you can have it push when you publish by clicking on the referenced dll and change the "Copy Local" option in properties to true. Then when you deploy use the publish function of the project.
This doesn't hard code a path when you publish, it just uses that path to do the compilation.
The published app will then look at the bin folder for that dll.